# Image used in SWT browser not being displayed in Mozilla

Tags: java, html, swt, mozilla

I am developing a java app with an embedded browser in eclipse.The browser page contains an image.I specified the browser to be mozila.The image is shown in IE but not in mozila.

This is a part of my code.

```
 String html = "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>HTML Test</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) html +="<br>" ;
        html += "<p style=\"text-align:center;color:blue;font-size:15px;\"><img      src=\"Information.png\">Enter the text you want to search for</BODY></HTML>";
    if(browser!=null)
    {
        browser.setText(html);
    }
```

First i tried giving the full directory path like

> C:\Users\vpalagum\Desktop\Projectimages\right2.gif

But it dint work and after googling learnt that for mozila relative adress should be given. So i placed the image in the src folder of project and gave a relative adress.A broken grey image is being shown.Mozilla firefox shows all other images perfectly during normal browsing.

Comment: Where exactly is the image located relative to the project root?

Comment: It is in the src folder inside project folder.I am using eclipse

Comment: Have you tried using `<img src=\"src/Information.png\">` then?

Comment: Just tried.Dint work.

Comment: Actually,if im including an image in a normal html file and using mozila,the image is supposed to be in the folder where html code doc is present.Only then it works.But here i dont have a seperate html doc so where do i place the image?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't test it here. Don't have XULRunner installed.